# Telomerase in tetrahymena

Tags: dna, rna, enzymes, telomere, protein-binding

In [this](http://www.ibiology.org/ibioseminars/genetics-gene-regulation/elizabeth-blackburn-part-1.html) amazing video, at 26:03 we see this image[image]

We now know that the telomerase contains a sequence complementary to the telomere sequence and so is able to do what it is capable of doing in this image.

My questions : What if we make a piece of dna with  five GGGGG at the 3' end ? Will the telomerase not work, as the RNA in telomerase has the sequence AACCCC and so won't be able to form complementary strand ? If so, has such a mutation been detected in any organism ie it's telomerase is unable to work just because it has a random insertion(maybe during replication) of one of the nucleotides in the telomere at the 3' end ?

Comment: Anyone who wishes to understand telomere and telomerase and want to know more about them from the discoverer of telomerase HERself please see the video I mentioned in the link! It's enlightening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is speculation, as I haven't done or read of the required experiment. However, I imagine that this would not be a problem.

You're right that the RNA template ([TERC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telomerase_RNA_component)) would not hybridize with a poly-G sequence, and so the telomerase would not be able to add more telomere repeats. You can imagine that the poly-G sequence is a cap, preventing telomerase activity.

However, without the telomere repeats other proteins are likely to recognize the chromosome end as a DNA break. Exonucleases would likely chew at the end of the chromosome until they got to the actual telomere sequence, which is bound by protective proteins (namely [Shelterin](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16166375)). With the poly-G region degraded, the end of the chromosome would now have the true telomere repeats, and telomerase would be able to add even more repeats.

Even if the poly-G region was bound by protective proteins, the telomeres naturally shorten with each replication cycle, due to the nature of [5' to 3' DNA replication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okazaki_fragment). Therefore, the poly-G region would eventually be removed revealing the true telomere repeats and allowing telomerase to extend the chromosome once again.

In a worst case scenario, rather than degrade the poly-G region the cell undergoes recombination between poly-G regions on multiple chromosomes, leading to either massive chromosomes or circular chromosomes. However, I'm sure these cells would die with some kind of massive mitotic failure.